# i want to make my menu bar resize automaticlyy within the theme

Tags: css, nav

I have added a nav menu background to my style sheet , and i found that when i zoom my browser , the menu it self dont resize like the the rest of my theme , its take another positions away from the theme structure...thats my nav css code :

```
#main-menu {
margin-left:184px;
width: 978px;
    height: 56px;
    background: url(images/nav_bg.png);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    }

#main-menu ul {
background: url(images/nav_bg.png);
    margin: 0;
    height: 56px;
    }

#main-menu ul li {
background: url(images/navh_bg.png);
    float: left;
    height: 56px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 25px;
    }

#main-menu ul li:last-child,
#main-menu ul li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
    }

#main-menu ul li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    height:56px;
    line-height: 56px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 4px;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    }

#main-menu ul li:hover { 
background: url(images/navh_bg.PNG) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    visibility: inherit;
color: #ffffff;
    /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
    }

#main-menu ul li a:hover {
background: url(images/navh_bg.PNG)no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    visibility: inherit;
    color: #ffffff;

    }
```

Comment: In short cut I want my meny bar resize auto with all resolutions like the rest of my theme

Answer (score 0):

you can use in all widths, margin and fontsize (%)

```
#main-menu {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 56px;
    background: url(images/nav_bg.png);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100%
}
```